# Django-storages and boto and REST

Tags: django, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, boto, django-storage

Good evening,

1. I am a bit confused about what Django-Storages is needed for? (http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) Does it simply provide a layer to continue using basic Django storages code, but with Amazon S3? If so, is that why it uses Boto?
2. I will want to use DevPay and Amazon S3. Will `s3boto` work with that? I read that for devpay to work with S3, the requests need to be in REST. Will streaming a video, or getting the URL of a picture work with DevPay? (Both on mobile and web browser.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

django-storages is a drop-in replacement for Django's FileSystem storage class, allow you to transparently upload images and files to S3 buckets (and various other storage systems). It uses Boto to connect to Amazon Web Services under the hood.

DevPay is completely separate from S3/Boto/django-storages. I've never used it personally, but you might want to have a look at [Stripe](http://stripe.com/). Simple. Effective. Very easy to integrate into Django.